# Pushing to github - strange white spaces

Tags: php, github

When I push my code into github repo and display random files, they contain some strange whitespaces, e.g.:

```
// 'auth'               => MPATH.'auth',            // Authentication module
// 'database'       => MPATH.'database',        // Database access
```

In my IDE the code is perfectly lined up, on github - it behaves like above, in totally random places. Is there any way to fix this?

I use tabs for indents.

Comment: that may happen when changing IDE too

Comment: Are you mixing tab literals  and spaces for alignment? If so, you probably have a different tab width defined than github does, or this could happen with just tab literals. If you need things aligned, always uses spaces for alignment. (that doesn't mean you have to use them for indentation, which is different)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange indenting for Java Eclipse project on Github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149750/strange-indenting-for-java-eclipse-project-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using spaces over tabs going forward. You can set your editor to input 2, 4 or how many spaces each time you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.I believe this will save you much headache, because a space is always exactly the same width, whereas tab width can always change depending on context.

For now you can convert the tabs like this

```
expand -t2 foo-tabs.php > foo-spaces.php
```